# Should I bother with setting NCHW for training and NHWC for testing?

Tags: tensorflow

https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#use_nchw_image_data_format

I've read that cuDNN has better performance with NCHW (feature maps on the second axis) but that NHWC is better on CPU (feature maps on last axis).

As of TensorFlow 1.2, I wonder if it's still recommended to manually support both formats, or if it's reasonable to expect tf.train, tf.layers etc. to automatically take care of dimension reordering as needed (I believe they should!). Manually supporting both data formats feels ugly and like a leaky abstraction with implementation details that I as a TensorFlow user should not have to know about, hence I'd like to avoid it.

Also, how much of a performance improvement would one reasonably expect to gain from GPU training with NCHW instead of NHWC?

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know where you found that CPU executions are faster in NHWC mode. Intel MKL library for DNN uses the NCHW format by default, and as I understand, uses yet another [opaque, SIMD-friendly format internally](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introducing-dnn-primitives-in-intelr-mkl). So it you go NCHW, at least you wouldn't have to maintain two versions.

I don't know what order of gain you could expect. As CuDNN uses the NCHW order itself, I suppose tensorflow does not convert formats back and forth at each layer, but converts back into NHWC only when needed (e.g. when you explicitly ask for the tensor values). So unless you do lots of exotic stuff outside of standard CuDNN operations, I would not be surprised if gains are minor. But it is just an uneducated guess.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I found the information that CPU executions are faster as NHWC on the link in my original post: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#use_nchw_image_data_format

Comment: I see. Sounds more like a historical justification of their default memory order than an up-to-date observation though, especially now that they are increasingly relying on Intel MKL for their CPU implementation.